# Set up Apache Spark with Yarn Cluster

Tags: apache-spark, bigdata, hadoop-yarn

I want to integrate Yarn using apache spark.I have installed spark , jdk and scala on my pc. My data is saved in Cassandra database.I have also created one another server for slave.

Spark version - 2.1.0
Scala version - 2.9.2
master(My PC) (IP :192.**.**.01)
slave server(IP :192.**.**.02)

Spark and scala also installed on my slave server. Do I need to install anything more on master or slave? If all installed then what should I do configuration for integrating YARN using spark.

Actually I am creating a word count program using cluster manager(YARN). My aim is to used YARN in my application.You can give me any more suggestion for that. Please help..

Answer (score 1):

- You need to install Hadoop 2x  to have yarn incorporated.Here is the
  [link](https://data-flair.training/blogs/install-hadoop-2-with-yarn/).
- Next,launch spark with Yarn in cluster mode `$ ./bin/spark-submit --class
  path.to.your.Class --master yarn --deploy-mode cluster [options] <app
  jar> [app options]`.You can refer [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/running-on-yarn.html)